# python can't use virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

i'm running Python 2.7 with my debian testing and i've a probleme using virtualenv.

Im trying to create a virtualenv on a partition which is mount like

```
/dev/sda5   /media/misc vfat    users,defaults,uid=1000,gid=1000,exec,umask=0 0 0
```

So, rights seems ok but virtualenv returns me :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/virtualenv", line 3, in <module>
virtualenv.main()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 938, in main
never_download=options.never_download)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1039, in create_environment
site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1186, in install_python
copyfile(join(stdlib_dir, fn), join(lib_dir, fn))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 430, in copyfile
copyfileordir(src, dest)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/virtualenv.py", line 405, in copyfileordir
shutil.copytree(src, dest, True)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 206, in copytree
raise Error, errors
shutil.Error: [('/usr/lib/python2.7/config/libpython2.7.so', 'seb/lib/python2.7/config     /libpython2.7.so', '[Errno 1] Operation not permitted')]
```

i've installed virtualenv with apt.
using virtualenv in my /home is successfull

can you help me ?

Comment: in your home works, in your partition it doesn't, means it's permissions issue... what's your permission table for /dev/sda5?

Comment: i agree with you but permissions are : drwxrwxrwx. I can touch a .py file and run it. that's why i don't understand

Comment: try the latest virtualenv version. Just download [`virtualenv.py`](https://raw.github.com/pypa/virtualenv/master/virtualenv.py) and run in the desired directory: `python virtualenv.py env`. See [the docs](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/#usage)

Comment: I don't /media/misc in the traceback. What is `seb/lib/python2.7/config     /libpython2.7.so`? Why is there space after `config`?

Comment: seb/lib/python2.7/config /libpython2.7.so is the virtualenv i'd like to create :) (seb) the space avec config is a missprint in my post don't care about

Answer (score 2):

fixed. I don't exactly why, but i've formated my partiton with a ntfs type resolves the issue.
It seems that fat32 system adds control over fstab